# Nested unordered list takes on style from parent

Tags: css

I have an unordered list that has a nested list in it. I have an active style for when a link is active (duh), but the problem I'm having is that my "electronic services" is active but for some reason the active color has been applied to it's (ul) children. I can't seem to get it off.

How do I make it so it only applies to the one electronic services link?

```
.left-cnt ul ul{display:none;}
.left-cnt ul.left-menu{width:85%; padding-bottom:15px;}
.left-cnt ul.left-menu>li.active a{color:#18ab4f; font-weight:500;}
.left-cnt ul.left-menu>li.active {background: url("images/bullet.png") no-repeat scroll left 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
.left-cnt ul.left-menu>li:hover ul{display:block;}
.left-cnt ul li{line-height:20px;}
.left-cnt ul a{color:#7b7d7e; font-size:16px; line-height: 25px;}
.left-cnt ul li:hover>a{color:#18ab4f;}
.left-cnt ul li:hover{background: url("images/bullet.png") no-repeat scroll left 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
```

Comment: For the above fiddle, I get "Spam detected. This fiddle has been disabled. If you feel this should not happen for this fiddle, please get in touch". Anyone else get this?

Comment: Another user noted he also is unable to see the Fiddle link, so I have removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [direct child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) to target anchor elements that are a direct child of `li.active`.

Therefore, change

```
.left-cnt ul.left-menu > li.active a
```

to:

```
.left-cnt ul.left-menu > li.active > a
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrkv5cdn/)

```
.left-cnt ul.left-menu > li.active > a {
    color:#18ab4f;
    font-weight:500;
}
```

Comment: That seems to work for the first tier, but i place (active) on the li item (child) of the eservices, that li item doesn't highlight

Comment: @Damien - Alright, then [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mfwsxvg7/) is what you want, I think.

Comment: Close... i was able to figure it out using your direction... this is more like it: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/mmtLgsL0/1/